# Integrate Spring Boot in a legacy application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I want to integrate Spring Boot in one of the existing application. So I decided to start with a POC first.
 I downloaded a sample working code from http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial and tried to integrate Spring Boot. I changed pom.xml and added a new Java class Application. Below are both of them.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.journaldev.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVCHibernate</artifactId>
<name>SpringMVCHibernate</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Application.java

```
package com.journaldev.spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;


@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("file:/home/gd_java/program_files/projects/SpringMVCHibernate/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml")
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

}

When I run application it gets deployed without any error. But When I am trying to access it I am getting below error on web browser.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Apr 15 20:15:17 IST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spring+boot+404

Comment: This simply means `/error` is not mapped. Something else has failed and there is no mapping for `/error`. Does anything else show up on your console?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@SpringBootApplication`annotation in Application.java file.